# Programmatically grow a figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Illustration]

How do I grow the size of a figure in matplotlib, to accommodate a variable number of subplots, while keeping the heights constant?

I'm plotting a large number of figures, which each consists of a main subplot (green) which should cover 90% of the height of the image. Added to that, I'm adding a variable number of annotation subplots (orange) which should each take up 10% height. In other words, the base case of a figure with one annotation would result in a figure of height 100%, and a figure with 5 annotations would have a total height of 140%

A command that allows me to plot the main plot then grow the figure as I add each subplot would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is an automatic option. I could be wrong. There is [`figure.set_figheight`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.set_figheight) which adjusts the size in inches. The problem is that the axes are defined relative to the figure dimensions, so any subplots on the figure before you resize are scaled to fill in the extra 40% space.

You would have to write a routine that both adjusts the height of the figure and scale and displace anything in the figure. Not impossible to do, but again I don't think this feature exists yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
br@ymir:~/temp$ python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:57:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> fig=plt.figure()
>>> fig.get_size_inches()
array([ 8.,  6.])
>>> fig.set_size_inches([8.,12.])
>>> ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
>>> ax.plot([1,1,2],[3,4,5],'ro-')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2428590>]
>>> ax1 = fig.add_subplot(212)
>>> ax1.plot([2,3,4],[8,9,11],'bs-')
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x2461450>]
>>> fig.subplots_adjust()
```

produces 
[image]

and you can easily fine-tune it further.